# gcc --as-needed linker flag not working

Tags: linux, gentoo, gcc

I have two computers with Gentoo, both on AMD64. I try to build a following program:

```
int main() {tgetent();}
```

The command to compile is:

```
 gcc -v 1.c -Wl,--as-needed -lncurses
```

On one computer it cannot find the function while on the other one it can. Without --as-needed flag it links properly. The versions of the compilers and binutils are the same.

Here are the logs on the first and second machine:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.7.3-r1/work/gcc-4.7.3/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/python --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5' --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m64 --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --disable-libgcj --enable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --enable-lto --without-cloog --without-ppl
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/cc1 -quiet -v 1.c -quiet -dumpbase 1.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase 1 -version -o /tmp/cckCeNIy.s
GNU C (Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) version 4.7.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include  search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) version 4.7.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 39edf3479a880e47daebbbc3740ccab0
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as -v --64 -o /tmp/cckazMHs.o /tmp/cckCeNIy.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.23.2
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../.. /tmp/cckazMHs.o --as-needed -lncurses -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home_old/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.7.3-r1/work/gcc-4.7.3/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/python --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5' --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --disable-altivec --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --disable-libgcj --enable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --enable-lto --without-cloog --without-ppl
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/cc1 -quiet -v 1.c -quiet -dumpbase 1.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase 1 -version -o /tmp/cc830JX6.s
GNU C (Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) version 4.7.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include  search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) version 4.7.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: d486e53a9a5b8aa6182027c91a2ba0e6
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccl4EIq9.o /tmp/cc830JX6.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.23.2
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../.. /tmp/ccl4EIq9.o --as-needed -lncurses -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/tmp/ccl4EIq9.o: In function `main':
1.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `tgetent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I'd look at your linker and its default options/setup/configuration.  gcc is really a controller which runs compiler (cc) and linker (ld) in order.   It passes -W options to the linker.   You might try compiling with gcc, but then linking by hand to test this, suggest 'ld --trace --verbose --as-needed -lncurses 1.o -o 1' (after 'gcc 1.c -o 1.o')  Placement of '-lncurses' in cmdline MAY affect success, see ld man pages on -l option and location in line effects.

Comment: Well, I've dug further and it turned out that ncurses package was after all compiled differently on two systems. Silly me. On the system with problem there was use flag tinfo needed for nvi, and it puts those symbols into libtinfo.

Comment: Silly Bear! ………